# Finding files by extension in a folder and displaying their contents

Tags: regex, shell, find

What I need to do is to find all the c files (.c file extensions) in a folder and its subfolders. Also it needs to print each c file's function names(not the entire contents).

What I did so far is:

```
find "$1" -type f -name *.c -exec echo {}":" \; -exec grep -i "(*)" {} \;
```

but the problem is that, it is supposed to be printed like this:

```
fs/folder/a.c:
int test_function()

fs/project_1/src/b.c:
void test_function_1(int loc)
int test_function_2(int loc)

fs/project_1/util/c.c:
FILE* test_function_3(char* name)
void test_function_4(FILE* file)
void test_function_5(FILE* file)
```

But the shell script I wrote above prints out like this:

```
fs/folder/a.c:
int test_function() {
fs/project_1/src/b.c:
void test_function_1(int loc) {
int test_function_2(int loc) {
fs/project_1/util/c.c:
FILE* test_function_3(char* name) {
void test_function_4(FILE* file) {
void test_function_5(FILE* file) {
```

1) Is there a way to remove those "{" regex and also put new lines between each files?

2) Also, when I execute the program, the order of the files printed as an output is always different. Can it be sorted? (When I try to -exec sort {} \, this makes the output totally wrong...)

3) Lastly, how can I make it occur an error message when the input(folder name)
is not a folder?
(eg) When executing ./findfn.sh abcd <- error "abcd is not a folder"

Can someone please help me out with this problems? I am stuck at this problems for hours... I would be very thankful if someone blows up my confusion... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `printf`:

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.c' -exec printf '\n%s:\n' {} \; -exec grep -i "(.*)" {} \;
```

However this approach will be much more efficient as it avoids forking a sub-shell for each file:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   printf '%s:\n' "$file"
   if grep -c '(.*)' "$file"; then
      grep "(.*)" "$file" | sed 's/{//g'
   else 
       echo 'no functions'
   fi
   echo
done < <(find "$1" -type f -name '*.c' -print0)
```

Comment: Sorry I went bed yesterday...
It is almost there!!
I just have to remove { after funtion_names() but | sed 's/{//g' | does not work here... how should I remove {??

Comment: And also, if I use above script you wrote, there is a new line at the very first line as well, and also there is "{" that I have to remove...

Comment: Yeah don`t worry I just figured it out, but I can I occur an error if c files in a folder do not contain any functions in its contents?

Comment: Is there any way to print something like "no functions" rather than printing nothing?

Comment: thank you anubhava! will be waiting for ur response!